# Linq to Entities - Retrieve entity with "self-reference" from Stored Procedure

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity, parent-child

I can't quite figure this out. I have a table called Employee with and Id field. The table also contains a ManagerId field which has a foreign key pointing to the Employee's Id field. When I add the table as an entity to my entity data model it creates the new Employee entity with an EmployeeChildren collection element and an EmployeeParent element. I can retrieve all employee's and have them put into a new instance of the Employee entity perfect. The employee entity will have many children, each child entity can have many children of their own and each one has a pointer back to it's parent.

What I need to do now is retrieve a subset of those employee's using a stored procedure. Right now, if I search for employee John Doe, who has 2 people above him, the stored procedure will return 3 rows.

EmployeeID ManagerId Name

1          null      Bill

2          1         Jane

3          2         John Doe

Here is my code to do the retrieval:

```
using (var entity = new TimeEntryEntities())
    {

         var employees =
                 from E in entity.EmployeeSearch(search)
                 orderby E.Name
                 select E;


         return employees.ToList<Employee>();
    }
```

Right now, this code returns 3 separate entities. How can I have it group them together into one?

Comment: Does this work as expected when you don't use the stored procedure?  If you retrieve a single employee directly with a LINQ query, are the "Managers" and "Reports" collections populated as they should be?

Comment: It does work but it doesn't come back the way I need it to. It will retrieve the employee and that entity will have a parent entity. The parent entity will have a parent and the child...and so on. I need it to start at the top level parent, not at the lower level child. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you are trying to flatten out the hierarchy so only one record is returned. Maybe Common Table Expression (CTE) in the stored procedure can help:
[Here is an alternate of a similar request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702584/how-can-i-easily-flatten-this-sql-server-heirarchy-into-an-inherited-inclusive-li):

Also [another example with more detail](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2005+-+TSQL/recursivequeriesinsql1999andsqlserver2005/1846/)  (but you have to register for free):

Comment: I'm using a CTE in the procedure to return the 3 rows. It finds the child row then using a CTE returns the parent...then the parent of the parent...etc. This results in 3 rows being returned from the database. Now I need to put those rows into my Employee entity. I'm wondering if I need to do this manually and forget about linq to entity in this case.

Answer (score -1):

You should return only the entity you're interested in. EF will retrieve the related entities automatically for you.
This would be easier to visualize if you we're not using a self-reference, this concept has got in the way.